# adjust axis and colours figure simPH package R

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I'm using the simPH package to plot hazard ratio's. As my variable is time, I would rather change the ticks and intervals at the x-axis to 0,30,60,90 etc instead of 0,50,100,150 which is currently plotted based on my data (x ranges from 0 to 180). As the simPH package uses ggplot2, I tried to change to code to: `simGG(Sim1, scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 180, by = 30)))` but unfortunately, this doesn't work. (This is the code for Sim1: `Sim1 <- coxsimLinear(surv, b= "time",  qi = "Relative Hazard", Xj=seq(1,180, by=0.1), nsim=100))`

Also, I would need to change the colours of the ribbons to greyscale and not blue as is default in this package. Does anyone has experience with adapting the default settings of this package? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code to solve this is:

```
G1 <- simGG(Sim1)
G1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 180, by = 30))
```